# Constantly problems with Python: Python was not found, can't open file…,

Tags: python, django, windows-10

For unknown reasons, I started to have constantly failures with python.

I started yesterday, not sure if I have a relation, but I installed Docked with WSL 2 Linux kernel, and PostgreSQL recently too.

The first problem, all my paths were deleted. I wrote again:

> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts

After, it starter to appear in the console:

> Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the
> Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App
> Execution Aliases.

After trying to fix it, uninstall Python completely and reinstall it. Show me something about getting from Microsoft Store. I did, I reinstalled Django and I added too new path which was recommended:

> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\Scripts

Started to work again (yesterday), but today it's not working again with this message:

> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe: can't
> open file 'D:\code\proyectWeb\manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file  or
> directory

It's like each new day, the python installation gets corrupted or something, and start to make me crazy. If anyone had similar problems or can have an idea about what is going on, I would greatly appreciate your help, thanks.

I have Windows 10, and the last versions of python, django and pip, because I updated after the first problems. After many weeks I got noproblems until yesterday.

Comment: Is python on path ie environmental variables??

Comment: It is:

● C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts
● C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\Scripts

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: maybe you should go back to older version - sometimes new versions have bugs and it is better to wait few months before people fix all problems.